# Fixing position of buttons in grid

Tags: css, angular, angular8

I am working on a angular app. I have following grid.

```
.grid {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 1fr);
    grid-gap: 2.5vw;
    grid-auto-rows: 35%;
}
```

This grid will make 4 rectangle in parallel something like this.

```
    ...   ....    ....   ...
    ...   ....    ....   ....
    ...   ....    ....   ....
```

These dotted lines represents rectangles. In these rectangles I have buttons. The problem I am facing is if I use *ngIf in button and when *ngIf becomes false. That particular button is not visible but when that particular button is not visible, all the other buttons behind it automatically moves up by 1 position. How I can fix the position of buttons in grid? I don't want button to move their positions

Answer (score 1):

It seems you are generating the buttons using inside `ngFor` loop like this.

```
<div class="grid">
  <button *ngFor="let i of inputs">...</button>
</div>
```

To resolve the problem of moving position when button is hidden by `*ngIf`, the good way is to put `div` as the main child of `grid` class and put button inside it as follows.

```
<div class="grid">
  <div *ngFor="let i of inputs">
    <button *ngIf="...">...</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

If you put `button` inside `div`, even if the button is hidden by `ngIf`, the div will still remain so the position won't be changed.

Comment: Another potential is to use an else block to add an empty div whenever a button doesn't exist in the `ngFor`. That way there's fewer pointless elements rendered